# Excel popup 'view cannot be displayed because it contains more data than is supported'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-online

I encountered a new a popup in Excel Online that I don't understand. I can't figure out the origin of the issue. The excel is built of tables, most of columns have a formula which length is about 8000 characters. All suddenly, the popup appears
[image]

Sorry it's in French. it might be translated into "We cannot display the content in this view because it contains more data than is supported." in English versions.

Why does it occurred? Is the data too large (up to 45 columns) for Excel Online? is the cumulated formula length to long? it seems to work well in Excel Desktop (2019 edition), but not on Excel Online in SharePoint.

I found this thread [the-content-in-this-view-cant-be-displayed](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/the-content-in-this-view-cant-be-displayed-as-it/b85849a7-d1f7-4d46-9dad-b281d386ef9c), which seems to deal with same issue, but no real anwser.